# AngularJs - Get scope in directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to get `scope` value in directive. The `scope.statesActive` is set from `controller` which calls the `directive`.

Here is the code from my directive :-

```
console.log(scope)
```

[image]

I tried to get the `statesActive` value like this :-

```
console.log(scope.statesActive[0].states[0])
```

It gives me result as `undefined`

How to get the value?

------------Added

```
$scope.statesList = function () {
            var query = {
                status: 'active'
            }

            StatesList.query(query).$promise.then(function (states) {
                $scope.states = states;                
            });
        };
```

Comment: Install [Batarang](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang/ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk?hl=en) It is a very helpful tool for debugging angular

Comment: @zeroflagL the questioner is the same....with so perfect solution till now... :)

Comment: It doesn't make sense to post the same question twice

Comment: Do makes sense...till right solution is found...which will be used further by anybody who gets stuck right here...

Answer (score 1):

Obviously the value is not defined when you call `console.log()`. It gets set later.

When you call `console.log(scope)` and inspect the object you don't get the state of the object at the time of the call, but its current state.

Comment: so how do i solve this?

Comment: @Anup You didn't post any code. Please show us the code where `scope.statesActive` gets set.

Comment: @Anup The code sets `$scope.states`, in the controller. How is `statesActive` set? Is it like `<directive states-active="states">` ? It seems that you get `states` via AJAX, so you cannot use it immediately. You could use `scope.$watch()` in your directive, to detect when the data is ready.

Comment: When i use `$watch`...i get data within that `watch`...but not outside it

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I see that you've edited. Well, try to go step by step, first `scope.statesActive`, then `scope.statesActive[0]` etc., I see no reason for it to return undefined from what you've shown.

Typo in `stateActive`, should be `statesActive`.

Comment: `scope.statesActive[0]` gives me `undefined` ... i have also tried various combinations here..like...`scope.statesActive[0].states[0]` and `scope.statesActive[0].states` and `scope.statesActive.states[0]`...but no proper result...

Comment: @Anup Try to recreate it in a fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Ok.Send your working file what the reason I found it.Immediately send your file